# "with considering" or "by considering"

Tags: prepositions

Is the usage of `with` in the sentence below correct?

> The user ensures the correctness of the program **with** considering the model.

Comment: In my opinion, I prefer nothing in between the 'program' and 'considering'.

Comment: Omitting the preposition leads to ambiguity. **By considering** is correct in this context. Alternatively **with considertion of**.

Comment: Consider *with (something)" vs. *by (some action)*. In your example, it is "considering".

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend: The user ensures the correctness of the program by considering the model.

Alternatively, you could even use: By considering the model, the user ensures the correctness of the program.

Best wishes!